# Posting data using urllib without SSL certificate validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, urllib, urlopen

I need to post data to a REST interface, however the receiving host is using a self-signed certificate (and this is not about to change) so I need to ignore the obvious certificate validation error that I receive.

My initial script looked like this:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode

post_url = "https://myserver.mydomain.com:30005/myapipath"
post_payload = { "event": { "Title": "Something, sometime, something, Python"} }
post_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

omi_post = Request(url=post_url, data=post_payload, headers=post_headers)

urlopen(omi_post)
```

And as mentioned, this generates the following stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1318, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1026, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 964, in send
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1400, in connect
>       server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 407, in wrap_socket
>       _context=self, _session=session)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 814, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 1068, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py",
>   line 689, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "send_data.py", line 16, in
>   
>       urlopen(post_it_already)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 223, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 526, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 544, in _open
>       '_open', req)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1361, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1320, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError:

So I found another post that talked about adding in an SSL context, which I did as follows:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

post_url = "https://myserver.mydomain.com:30005/myapipath"
post_payload = { "event": { "Title": "Something, sometime, something, Python"} }
post_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

post_it_already = Request(url=post_url, data=post_payload, headers=post_headers)

urlopen(post_it_already, context=ctx)
```

However this generates the following stacktrace (no matter how much I shake my fist at it):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "send_data.py", line 15, in
>   
>       urlopen(post_it_already, context=ctx)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 223, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 526, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 544, in _open
>       '_open', req)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1361, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1318, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
>   "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1064, in _send_output
>       + b'\r\n' TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

I'm at a loss as to why it's complaining about concatenating a string with a bytes object.  I assume it doesn't like my string type URL and my data type payload and headers?  However I'm unsure what to do next.

Or is this a classic case of someone taking 2 separate sample codes and expecting them to work together when they are in fact like peanuts and bubble gum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `post_payload` should be of type 'bytes' rather than 'str'.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

> class urllib.request.Request ...
>
> ...
>
> For an HTTP POST request method, data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.parse.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns an ASCII string in this format. It should be encoded to bytes before being used as the data parameter.
>
> ...

You can convert `post_payload` to bytes using the `.encode()` method as detailed in [this Python urllib howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html).

This is separate to the SSL validation issue, but presumably because it attempted to POST data, the HTTPS connection was successfully established.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I fell into the common trap of blindly building my code off other code snippets.  I should have read the documentation first.

I added used .parse to URL encode it first, and then .encode to convert it to bytes, exactly as per the documentation you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @contextlib.contextmanager decorator with requests module instead. It's a much simpler approach.

The below code works just fine

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    old_request = requests.Session.request
    requests.Session.request = partialmethod(old_request,verify=False)

    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'Unverified HTTPS request')
    yield

    warnings.resetwarnings()
    requests.Session.request = old_request
```

What the above code does is it generates a partial method for requests.Session.request with '`verify=False`' and filters any warnings that say '`Unverified Https request`'.

```
with no_ssl_verification:
   request = requests.post( 
                           url,
                           json={
                                    'name' : some_name
                                },auth(username,password)
                           )
```

Hope it helps, please let me know in case you find a better solution.